# Wordpress Plugin & Paths

Tags: wordpress

Hey guys I have a plugin and its displaying info on /courses.php (using theme)

How can I get it to display info on /courses/single_course.php

I figured I'd just have to make a /courses/ folder in theme and have single_course.php inside that. However this doesn't seem to work.

I've tried googling but I'm struggling to figure out the keywords to solve this problem! ^_^

**OK edit cause nobody is understanding:**

- I have plugin working. This is a custom plugin
- I want to know how to make the following work http://www.example.com/plugin/index.php  http://www.example.com/plugin/index.php
- Currently to make http://www.example.com/plugin work you just need to create plugin.php in the theme directory and give a callback to a function in the plugin.
- Creating /wp-content/theme/themename/plugin/index.php did not work as anticipated.

Comment: your plugin file should go inside like this - htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\mypluginfile.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WP uses specific directories for placing its themes and plugins tom maintain organization standards.

```
// Pointing to theme WP themes directory
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/wp_content/themes/"  
// Pointing to theme WP plugins directory
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/wp_content/plugins/"
```

or you can use the built in functions in wordpress

```
// for themes in any php file after headers
get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom_script.js'
// for plugins in you main plugin class
plugins_url('/js/newscript.js', __FILE__);
```

I would recommend keeping plugins in plugins and themes in themes.  What you may be looking for is creating some extra plugin features which will require you to include you extra php functions and classes when the plugin in question is loaded.

First create a folder in under your plugin directory and chmod it with proper web securities

```
cd /path/to/wordpress/install/wp-content/plugins/your-plugin/
mkdir php
chmod 755
```

Next either copy or create and edit the new single_courses.php file. I've listed a quick method below if you are creating the new file from scratch. Otherwise just cp it over. In both cases we need to insure proper web access right using chmod.

```
cd /path/to/wordpress/install/wp-content/plugins/your-plugin/
echo -n "/*Extra Plugin Functions*/" > single_courses.php
chmod  644 single_courses.php
```

Now we need to be sure to include the new file in our main plugin file

```
/* Main Plugin File :: ./wp-content/plugins/your-plugin/theplugin.php */
...
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/wp_content/plugins/you-plugin/php/single_courses.php"
...
```

Thats the basic way to go about it. Use the same process for hooking theme php files as well.  Always make sure when creating directories and files on your server that proper security is put into effect or you open up your web directory and or server to get hacked.

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 1):

You have to give us more information on what plugin you are using and what you are trying to achieve. The solution may be as simple as pasting a Plugin provided shortcode into the post area of the desired page. Alternatively you may have to edit the plugin itself.

Comment: This is a plugin i am making. I understand how to get the content to show on a certain page. What I dont understand is how wordpress handles paths when I want to go into a folder.. EG: /courses/whatever.php